# Forward Lookup Zone Domain, Name Server IP "Unknown"

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-zone

I have added the first new 2012r2 DC to an existing domain, that is running on 2003 servers. After getting it all setup, ADDS replicating, DNS replicating, DHCP setup etc. Everything I think seems to be working but I've noticed an issue, I think?  in DNS..

In the Forward Lookup Zones if I go into the properties of a zone, and go to the Name Servers tab.  The entry for the new DC/DNS 'ZEUS' has an IP Address listed as 'Unknown'.  Have I done something wrong, not set something up correctly?  Is it normal that I have to manually enter this IP Address?  I don't recall having to manually enter the Name Server IPs for other domains I've configured in the FLZ.

Image attached of the properties window.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I feel as though something isn't right here and this is the first time I've added a new DC to an existing domain. This server is supposed to be taking over as the two others listed are 2003 and slated for decommissioning.

[image]

It is a fresh install of 2012r2, fully updated, ADDS Role installed, promoted to DC, and I let replication take care of populating DNS on the new server. I haven't done much of any customized configuration, I thought allowing replication would take care of things.

Comment: You should manually resolve it. Click edit, then click resolve. It will be OK.

Comment: Thank you,  I wasn't sure if I'd done something wrong in setting up the new DC.  I did just manually resolve the IP address for the new DC on all the FLZs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you, I wasn't sure if I'd done something wrong in setting up the new DC. I did just manually resolve the IP address for the new DC on all the FLZs.